# InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements. In Asp.net Core MVC with Entity framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core

I am getting this error one of my projects.

> InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements.

here is my code in this I am trying to create auto-generated Id with string format.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
    {
        int id = _db.Patient.Max(item => item.Id)+1;

        ViewBag.autoid = "BL0000"+id.ToString(); 
        return View();
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
    {
        //x = _db.Patient.Max(item => item.Id);
        x=_db.Patient.DefaultIfEmpty().Max(item => item == null ? 1 : item.Id+1);


        ViewBag.autoid = "BL0000"+x.ToString(); 
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `max` method will throw the InvalidOperation exception if the sequence contains no elements. - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=netframework-4.8

You could use some extension methods like this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18100382/38024

```
public static T MaxOrEmpty<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
{
    return query.DefaultIfEmpty().Max();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements.

As the error message said,you do not have such elements in your `Patient`.So you need to judge whether it contains item or not.

Try this:

```
var data = _db.Patient.Select(item => item.Id);
if(data.Count()==0)
{
    int id = 1; 
}
else
{
    int id = data.Max() + 1;
}
```